# Unable to get recently added records with getchanges method

Tags: c#, .net, datatable, ado.net, dataadapter

This is my table:

**Student**:`StudentId int PK autoincrement,Name varchar(20)`

When I am adding new row to data table and updating it to send it to database then it works fine but I am trying to get recently added rows then I am getting null.

This is my code:

```
 using (var connection = new SqlConnection("MyConnectionstring"))
            {
                connection.Open();
                SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter();
                SqlCommandBuilder builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter);

                adapter.SelectCommand = new SqlCommand("select * from Student", connection);


                DataTable dt = new DataTable();
                adapter.Fill(dt);

                DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
                row["Name"] = "Abc";
                dt.Rows.Add(row);
                adapter.Update(dt);
                var addedRecords = dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added); //getting null here
                connection.Close();
            }
```

However I have added student `Abc` but I am getting null in this line:

```
var addedRecords = dt.GetChanges(DataRowState.Added); //getting null here
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [this MSDN page for DataAdapter.Update()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.common.dataadapter.update(v=vs.110).aspx):

> 7. DataRow.AcceptChanges is called. This will raise both the
>      DataTable.RowChanging and DataTable.RowChanged events for the updated
>      DataRow.

AcceptChanges is being called for you by Update().

If we look at [the MSDN page for AcceptChanges()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarow.acceptchanges(v=vs.110).aspx):

> When invoking AcceptChanges, the EndEdit method is implicitly called
>   to end any edits. If the RowState of the row was Added or Modified,
>   the RowState becomes Unchanged. If the RowState was Deleted, the row
>   is removed.

That's why your `GetChanges()` call isn't returning anything -- there are no changes anymore.

Answer (score 2):

maybe after `adapter.Update(dt);` there is no Change anymore?

Comment: can you please put on some details?

Answer (score 1):

Once you have updated your `datatable`, there is no more changes pending, so `GetChanges` return you null as expected

Answer (score 1):

Once you load the Datatable.

You will have to say 
`Datatable.AcceptChanges();` **for the initial commit**

Then when you run `GetChanges`, it should return the new `row` inserted.

**Update:** Use `GetChanges` after `insert`operation.

Comment: when i use this Datatable.AcceptChanges(); then my changes to my database table doesnt happens